# Making an application a known service, to kerberize the application

Tags: java, unix, kerberos

I have created an application, and have a kerberos realm - i wish to be able to 'kerberize' this application. Im not 100% of the details of how to do this but, is there a way you can set the service name of any given application so that you can add it to the kerberos keytab?

Any tutorials or code samples are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the [JDK 6 Security documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html), more specifically [Single Sign-on Using Kerberos in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html).

Comment: had a look before, just had another look and it has became clearer :)